# Delete AWS WAF webAcl

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf

I am trying to delete a AWS WAF WebAcl that was created using Firewall Manager few months ago, but someone has removed the Firewall Manager policy, probably without ticking the "delete all policy resources" checkbox, so after this the webAcl remains existing, but I can't delete it.
When I try to remove the webAcl I got the following error message:

`Error You don't have permissions to delete the resource because it's managed by Firewall Manager.`

Since the firewall manager policy doesn't exist anymore, I don't have any idea on how to delete this resource. I also opened a case with AWS support from another account that I pay for developer support and the guy said that only their service team could solve this, but I can't believe the only way to delete a webacl is paying them for it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fms/2018-01-01/APIReference/API_DeletePolicy.html

I tried to remove the webAcl, but seems to be impossible since the source was a firewall manager policy. By checking Cloudtrail logs I couldn't find who deleted the policy (probably it was more than 90 days ago). I also tried removing it via CLI and asking for help to the AWS support (maybe they could send me a doc to solve it), but no way.

There are any way that I can solve this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "AWS WAF > Web ACLs > Associated AWS resources" and remove
2. Disassociate alb resources
3. Delete Web ACLS